# Error while installing TensorFlow with pip

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow

**While I try to install TensorFlow I get this error :**

```
(venv) olivierskonieczny@MacBook-Pro-olivier AI % python3 -m pip install tensorflow-macos

Collecting tensorflow-macos
  Using cached tensorflow_macos-2.7.0-cp38-cp38-macosx_11_0_arm64.whl (179.0 MB)
....
....
....
Building wheels for collected packages: h5py
  Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × Building wheel for h5py (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      running build_ext
      Loading library to get build settings and version: libhdf5.dylib
      error: Unable to load dependency HDF5, make sure HDF5 is installed properly
      error: dlopen(libhdf5.dylib, 0x0006): tried: 'libhdf5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.dylib' (no such file), '/private/var/folders/rh/4d7_g4zj06l16r4kl40s7rcm0000gn/T/pip-install-bukptyvu/h5py_993a67c380d14b6788f3e17bb8badb62/libhdf5.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libhdf5.dylib' (no such file)
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for h5py
Failed to build h5py
ERROR: Could not build wheels for h5py, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

I try to install p5py, PEP517 and still nothing works.

```
% pip --version
pip 22.0.2 from /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)
```

As you can see I've got newest pip version.

Im using Mac OS X newest version
MacBookPro with M1

Please help me ?

Comment: Does installing other packages work, or is it just TensorFlow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have an MacBook Pro with M1 Pro chip and I had the same problem as you.
For the moment the only solution I found is to use an environment with conda.

This help me: https://caffeinedev.medium.com/how-to-install-tensorflow-on-m1-mac-8e9b91d93706

### Here is what I did to make it work

**1. Install Xcode (few hour for me)**

From the Apps Store:

https://apps.apple.com/fr/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12

or

With command line:

```
xcode-select --install
```

**2. Download Miniforge**

https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge/releases/latest/download/Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh

**3. In the directory where you downloaded the previous file**

```
chmod +x Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

**4. Execute Miniforge**

```
./Miniforge3-MacOSX-arm64.sh
```

Press enter, yes, enter... Install complete !

**5. Turn off base environment**

```
conda config --set auto_activate_base false
```

**6. Create environment**

```
conda create --name conda_tf python=3.8
```

**7. Use the previous environment**

```
conda activate conda_tf
```

**8. Install tensorflow depencies**

```
conda install -c apple tensorflow-deps
```

**9. Install tensorflow**

```
 pip install tensorflow-macos
```

### To remember:

To get out of the environment:

```
conda deactivate
```

To enter from the environment:

```
conda activate conda_tf
```

Answer (score -1):

I fix this by following Apple Developer Docs: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

I uninstall Miniforge

```
# Remove the root prefix
rm -rf $(conda info --base)

# Configuration file, common between conda installations
rm ~/.condarc
# Environment locations and system information
rm -rf ~/.conda
```

and then I follow this Apple docs, works for me