# How do you install tensorflow on an Apple M1 pro silicon chip?

Tags: tensorflow, apple-m1

I have had many many errors when trying to install tensorflow on my new M1 pro chip computer. Any tips for a smooth installation??

Comment: Did you try following the steps discussed [here](https://naturale0.github.io/2021/01/29/setting-up-m1-mac-for-both-tensorflow-and-pytorch)

Comment: I run tensorflow with conda here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70956173/error-while-installing-tensorflow-with-pip/71272130#71272130